# Loop through array of multiple images to upload individually to AWS s3 ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

Im building an upload page that is supposed to take multiple images and upload them to aws s3 using AWS amplify storage.

**Im having a few issues**

- I need to encode all images to base64 format before uploading.
- It only allows one image to be uploaded at a time, so I need to loop through the array of files and upload each one individually.
- i am unable to get the name of the file by using `file.name`.

How should I loop through the array of image`files` encode them in base64, and upload each one individually?

The below code works for uploading one image at a time, but the file name is undefined.

```
 const file = useRef(null);

 function handleFileChange(event) {

        file.current = btoa(event.target.files); 

   console.log(event.target.files) ///// length: 7
                           /// 0: File {name: "921 crest road (19 of 91).jpg", lastModified: 1579836842179, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 23 2020 22:34:02 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 13998488, …}
                          /// 1: File {name: "921 crest road (20 of 91).jpg", lastModified: 1579836859659, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 23 2020 22:34:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 14433420, …}
                         /// 2: File {name: "921 crest road (21 of 91).jpg", lastModified: 1579836860868, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 23 2020 22:34:20 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 14524865, …}
                        /// 3: File {name: "921 crest road (22 of 91).jpg", lastModified: 1579836861497, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 23 2020 22:34:21 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 13995939, …}
                       /// 4: File {name: "921 crest road (23 of 91).jpg", lastModified: 1579836884687, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 23 2020 22:34:44 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 13982365, …}
                      /// 5: File {name: "921 crest road (24 of 91).jpg", lastModified: 1579836885360, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 23 2020 22:34:45 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 14288288, …}
                     /// 6: File {name: "921 crest road (25 of 91).jpg", lastModified: 1579836886846, lastMod

            console.log(file.current) //// undefined
  }


    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setShowLoading(true);

    try {

            console.log(file.name) ///undefined

            const filename = `${job.jobId}---${file.name}`;

            const stored = await Storage.put(filename, file.current, {
                contentType: file.type
        });

         } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
            console.log(e.message)
            }
         setShowLoading(false);
    }



  var centerText = {textAlign: "center"}

  return(
      <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
          <IonBackButton/>
        </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Upload Images</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>  
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

      <input multiple="true" type="file" onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)}></input>
      <IonButton  expand="block" color="primary" strong="true" size="default" type="submit" >Upload</IonButton>

      </form>

    </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
    );


  }


export default withRouter(JobInfo);
```

**Updated Code** --still not working!

```
const file = useRef(null);

  function extractInfo(file) {
        console.log(file)
     return { 
      name: file.name,
      type: file.type,
      content: btoa(file.content),
   };

}

    async function handleFileChange(event) {
    file.current = event.target.files;

  }

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
   const result = await Promise.all(
      file.current.files
          .map(extractInfo)
          .map(uploadFile)
   );
        console.log(file.files)
    }


    async function uploadFile(file) {

         setShowLoading(true);

        try {

  const filename = `${job.jobId}-${file.name}`;

  const stored = await Storage.put(filename, file.current, {
    contentType: file.type
  });


  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
    console.log(e.message)

  }
 setShowLoading(false);
}
  var centerText = {textAlign: "center"}

  return(
      <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
          <IonBackButton/>
        </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Upload Images</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>  
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

       <input multiple type="file" ref={file} onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)}></input></input>
      <IonButton  expand="block" color="primary" strong="true" size="default" type="submit" >Upload</IonButton>

      </form>

    </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
    );


  }


export default withRouter(JobInfo);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to use ref in your input element.
Using Promise.all to chain all the promises.

So your problem can be solved by something like this:

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function Uploader() {
   const file = useRef({});
   
   function readContent(file) {
      return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
         const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = () => accept({
            name: file.name,
            type: file.type,
            content: reader.result
         });
         reader.onerror = () => reject();
      });
   }
  
   function upload(file) { // fake upload
   
      return new Promise(accept => {
         setTimeout(() => accept(file), 1000);
      });
   }
   
   function onSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      const filesAsArray = [...file.current.files];
      const fileInfo = Promise.all(filesAsArray.map(readContent))
          .then(files => Promise.all(files.map(upload)))
          .then(console.log);
      
      return false;
   }
   
   return (
     <div>
       <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
         <input ref={file} type="file" multiple={true} />
         <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
       </form>
     </div>
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Uploader />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!! I appreciate the help. How would I go about properly adding the ref to the input?

Comment: im assuming since im using ```file = useRef(null);```, it would just be ```ref={file}```?

Comment: im also getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```.

Comment: Updated the answer with more detail snippet.